# WPF passing an UserControl to a View

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, user-controls

I have a class which should display a question and depending on what the question is asking for, provide different types of user inputs. The questions should be configurable, because of this I cannot hard code the questions and inputs. For the user inputs I have created a few different `UserControl`s which have different properties.

For example:

- An input which represents a multiple choice question which will need the different choices as a parameter
- An input which asks for a value

I have a base class for retrieving the value of the different inputs, but the parameters for displaying differ, therefore I could not include them there.

My idea was that I could construct the `UserControl`s from code and bind them to the view, but I could not find a way how to do it.

Then I would have something like:

`public UserControl Control { get; }`

and in the view something like:

`<someTag UserControl="{Binding Control}" />`

Do you have an idea how I can achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Answer (score -1):

I would approach this as having a user control and view model for each question type and then just controlling the visibility and content of the controls with binding. So the xaml would just have the controls on top of each other, all the same size. Whenever one is visible, the others are collapsed. You could also have one view model with all the question properties.